# How to avoid 'explicit constructor call not allowed' error

Tags: mql4

Does somebody know, how to avoid the next compilation error?

```
explicit constructor call not allowed
```

Is it possible to call a superclass-constructor inside a children class?

Thanks!

Comment: as you might have already noticed, Community Moderators are keen on closing in silence while some directions might help you understand why -- your post would be less attracting these Hawk Eye Punishers, if you would have posted code-snippet, where the error message directs ( Line#, Column# ) at the very end of the **`[[[ possible loss of data due to type conversion !2015-09-18___!EA 2xkAMA 01 2015-09-18_msMOD_4.21.mq4 714 37 `]]]**

Comment: with all due respect, would you kindly consider posting an MCVE with line number indication, incl. the full copy of the compiler error? ( yes, right-click, copy / paste ). **`#SOreadytohelp`**